# How can I compare two Strings using comparable interface?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparable

The code provided below is used for sorting `int` values. What I want to do now, is to sort them into `String`s.

```
public class Comparable5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet ts = new TreeSet();
        ts.add(new Student1(2, "Thilan"));
        ts.add(new Student1(1, "Kamal"));
        ts.add(new Student1(3, "Nimal"));

        System.out.println(ts);
    }
}

class Student1 implements Comparable<Student> {

    int id;
    String name;

    public Student1(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.id + ":" + this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student o) {
        if (o.name.equals(this.name)) {
            return -1;
        } else if (o.name.equals(this.name)) {
            return +1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to ascend names using Comparable interface. I have used `equals()` method, however I was unable to get ascending order. I tried comparing different objects using comparable interface. I have used a constructor that has two parameters.

I have already done sorting IDs, but was unable to sort them by names(String). How can I sort Strings using `compareTo()` method in Comparable interface?

Comment: Best thing to do is to start by reading the [class java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String))

Comment: Why don't you do `o.name.compareTo` ?

Comment: Thanks for the help.i have figure out the way.we can.yes we can use override  compareTo().

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
 @Override
 public int compareTo(Student o) {
   return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
 }
```

is "all" you need.

But of course, what you really need to understand is the **idea** behind these `compareTo()` methods. Your code implies that you don't. You return 0 when the two things are **equal**. Only then!

In your case, you can delegate all that work to the `compareTo()` implementation of the String class (which will use lexicographical sorting to compute the result), see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_compareto.htm) for example.

But as said: your real problem is the lack of understand *why* you are doing things! Beyond that: please note that references can be *null*. My example is just that: an example. In real world code, you would have to do much more, like thinking which values could be null, and how your code should react to that, in order to avoid exceptions flying around.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are comparable (i.e. it implements `Comparable<String>`), so you can call the String's `compareTo()` method.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student o) {
    return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
}
```

If you want to reverse the order, swap the `this` and `o`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
 public int compareTo(Student student) {
   return this.name.compareTo(student.name);
 }
```

Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer always requires an explanation on how this code helps.

Answer (score 0):

Note that with this

```
class Student1 implements Comparable<Student>
```

you will probably run into problems. Looking at the javadoc for `Comparable`, you

> must ensure sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x)) for all x and y

and

> that the relation is transitive: (x.compareTo(y)>0 && y.compareTo(z)>0) implies x.compareTo(z)>0.

This means that you also need to make sure that `Student implements Comparable<Student1>` with a proper comparison.

It does not feel like this is a road you want to go down.